# How to join into a comma-separated string from array of arrays (multidimensional-array)?

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Ok, I know that to get a comma-seperated string from a string array in PHP you could do

```
$stringA = array("cat","dog","mouse");
$commaSeperatedS = join(',', $stringA);
```

But what if I have an array of arrays(not a simple string array)?

```
$myAssociativeA = 
      array(
           [0] => array("type"=>"cat", "sex"=>"male")
           , [1] => array("type"=>"dog", "sex"=>"male")
      );
```

and my goal is to get a comma-seperated string from a specific property in each array, such as "type"? Ive tried

```
$myGoal = join(',', $myAssociativeA{'type'});
```

My target value for `$myGoal` in this case would be `"cat,dog"`.
Is there a simple way without having to manually loop through each array, extract the property, then do a join at the end?

Comment: Try to use **implode** function:  `$myGoal = implode(',', $myAssociativeA{'type'});`

Comment: What would be your expect output? (@bcesars join and implode is the same)

Comment: @bcesars, I have tried implode, it gave me an error

Comment: @Rizier123, I have updated my question with my hoped for output

Comment: @AmmarCSE see my answer below

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just get the column which you want with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and simply implode it with [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php))

```
echo implode(",", array_column($myAssociativeA, "type"));
```

Comment: I like your suggestion using array_column. Is there a version of the function 'array_column' compatible with PHP versions < 5.5?

Comment: @AmmarCSE You could use this implementation: https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php Or do it with `array_map()`. But I think we live in 2015 so you should have at least php 5.5

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to return the key you want:

```
array_walk($myAssociativeA, function(&$value, $key, $return) {
  $value = $value[$return];
}, 'type');

echo implode(', ', $myAssociativeA); // cat, dog
```

Useful for older PHP versions - @Rizier123's answer using `array_column()` is great for PHP 5.5.0+

Answer (score 2):

You can use this if you have PHP < 5.5.0 and >= 5.3.0 (thanks to [@Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218909/how-to-join-into-a-comma-separated-string-from-array-of-arrays-multidimensional/29219146?noredirect=1#comment46648515_29219146)) and you can't use `array_column()`

```
<?php

$myAssociativeA = array(array("type"=>"cat", "sex"=>"male"), array("type"=>"dog", "sex"=>"male"));

$myGoal = implode(',', array_map(function($n) {return $n['type'];}, $myAssociativeA));

echo $myGoal;
?>
```

EDIT: with the recommendation in the comment of [@scrowler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218909/how-to-join-into-a-comma-separated-string-from-array-of-arrays/29219146#comment46647794_29219146) the code now is:

```
<?php

$myAssociativeA = array(array("type"=>"cat", "sex"=>"male"), array("type"=>"dog", "sex"=>"male"));
$column = 'type';

$myGoal = implode(',', array_map(function($n) use ($column) {return $n[$column];}, $myAssociativeA));

echo $myGoal;
?>
```

Output:

> cat,dog

Read more about `array_map` in:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: heh, I dont know why people voted you down. It worked for me on PHP < 5.5

Comment: @AmmarCSE they are crazy and sick!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'd assume that it's because it gives no ability to have a dynamic column (type) since you've hard coded it into the callback

Comment: @scrowler Thanks, I will edit with your recommendation, but not all the answers have this and they are not downvoted.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer the two upvoted answers have that flexibility ;)

Comment: @scrowler see the Rizier123 answer, only works with the column "type"

Comment: Just to add this here, this answer isn't really that much backwards compatible it's only for: `PHP 5 >=5.3`!

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Both. [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) are introduced in PHP 5.3 so the gab to 5.5 isn't to big and also we live in 2015 so for what do we have `array_column()` to wait until 2020?

Comment: @Rizier123 I agree with you, but I see many peoples in SO that don't have PHP 5.5.0, they will have their reasons

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer *but I see many peoples in SO that don't have PHP 5.5.0* Me too! I also saw many people in 2014 which didn't had PHP 5.5, but now we live in 2015 and PHP 7 is right before our doors! So why do we wait? We just can open the door and use it!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to loop over the array and generate the string yourself.

```
<?php
   $prepend = '';
   $out = '';
   $myAssociativeA = array(
      array('type' => 'cat'),
      array('type' => 'dog')
   );

   foreach($myAssociativeA as $item) {
      $out .= $prepend.$item['type'];
      $prepend = ', ';
   }
   echo $out;
?>
```

You could easily turn this into a function.

```
<?php
   function implode_child($array,$key) {
     $prepend = '';
     $out = '';
     foreach($array as $item) {
        $out .= $prepend.$item[$key];
        $prepend = ', ';
     }
     return $out;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, under assumption that your assoc array fields are ordered always the same way you could use snippet like this. Yet you still need to iterate over the array.

```
$csvString = "";
foreach ( $myAssociativeA as $row ) {
    $csvRow = implode(",", $row);
    $csvString .= $csvRow . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Now if you don't want to store whole CSV in a variable (which you should not do) take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fputcsv.asp and see an example how to put it directly into the file.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that there is a difference between CSV (a formatting standard) and comma delimited

Comment: I agree - CSV standard contains additional details and not just the delimiter. From the question I've got under impression that he's problem is how to serialize assoc array so I focused on that issue.